# How to pass the whole row as an argument to an UDF in Spark (Java) and return same row with altered column values?

Tags: java, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-dataset

My usecase is, where a spark UDF takes a Row as an input and returns same row with altered columns based on some dynamic conditions generated on go in a hash map broadcast. All UDF has to do is get the columns from the HashMap alters it with the specified condition and returns a new row with some existing values from input row and some updated values derived from the broadcast HashMap conditions. If not, returns the input row as is.
I am not sure how to call this UDF on an entire row and how in the UDF can pick a certain dynamic column on the basis on its name and apply the conditions.
and since this is a dynamic and generic udf, i cannot make custom StrutType, it has to be dynamic

```
so My data looks like, where a,b,c and d are column names
a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |
12 |  ac | qa  |  rt |
```

Map looks like this

```
a -> a*2+b
b -> c+d
```

so for all the values in a and b should be altered as per map values. This map is broadcasted and is dynamic. the function must be capable of taking in any row and read the map and manipulate accordingly
so am expecting output be like

```
a    |  b    |  c  |  d  |
24ac |  qart | qa  |  rt |


 and the next dataset can be 
    q  |  p  |  c  |  d  |
    0  |  !@ |  R% |  qa |
```

Map will look like this

```
q -> q^2+2
c -> q+p+c+d
```

so am expecting output be like

```
q    |  p    |  c       |  d  |
2    |  !@   | 0!@R%qa  |  rt |
```

all dynamical handled

Comment: An alternative would be to convert it to an RDD and use `map`.

Comment: the dataset has like 500mil records, am not sure conversion of a row to map and rewinding map to row again will help,, but am new to it, will you help is a pesudo code, of the idea?

Comment: Can you update the question with a more concrete example of what you want to do (some code, input example and wanted output). Hopefully there is a more efficient way to solve it than what I suggested.

Comment: @Shaido explained with sample output

Comment: It seems to be possible to use fold on the Map and use mutliple `withColumn` to sovle it (at least in Scala, not sure about Java). Is it possible to add (with `+`) a number as well and not only columns? That would make it significantly harder to solve. The idea is basically to convert the Map to somthing like multiple statements such as `withColumn("a", concat($"a"*2, "b"))` which seems to be possible. However, in this way the final result would depend on the order of execution so maybe it's not suitable here.

Comment: Considering the second added example, using `df.rdd.map{ case Row(a,b,c,d) => ... }` (Scala) would probably be the way to go.